# Why does this input range push content downwards?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to align a vertical range input beside a column of labels. The input will have steps so the little bubble will always sit beside a label, and I have gotten the heights matching, so that's no problem.

However, no matter how I structure the two boxes (the input vertical range on the left and the labels on the right), the input always pushes the first label down, almost like it was a display: inline-block element.

HTML:

```
<div class="cell-left">
  <input type="range" orient="vertical" min="0" max="3" step="1" />
</div>
<div class="cell-right">
  <div class="row">Hello</div>
  <div class="row">Hello</div>
  <div class="row">Hello</div>
  <div class="row">Hello</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=range] {
  writing-mode: bt-lr; /* IE */
  -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical; /* WebKit */
  width: 8px;
  height: 4rem;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.cell-left {
  display: table-cell;
}
.cell-right {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/byn4kv0z/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### Short answer

That's expected behavior of `vertical-align: baseline` (the implicit default value). You can use:

```
.cell-right {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/byn4kv0z/1/)

---

### Explanation

Both the range input and the second table cell's text are part of the same [inline formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting). Regarding the default `vertical-align` value (`baseline`), the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) says:

> **baseline**
>   Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box. If the box does not have a baseline, align the bottom margin edge with the parent's baseline.

This means the range input's bottom is aligned with the parent box's baseline, and so is the second cell's first line box's baseline. Here you can see where parent box's baseline is:

[image: parent box's baseline]

That is because the vertical range input stretches the containing line box, resulting in the effect you see.

---

As for your remark:

> the input always pushes the first label down, almost like it was a display: inline-block element.

The range input is a [replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element), and its behavior is indeed nearly identical to an `inline-block` element.

Comment: If anyone can find inaccurate info in this answer, I'd love to have it pointed out. This would greatly help me improve my knowledge as well as the content which I'm contributing to the site.

Comment: I've rewritten certain parts for extra clarity.

Answer (score 8):

That is expected behaviour. The `vertical-align` property by default is set to `baseline` which leads to the result. Changing the `vertical-align` property to `top` would give you the result you are looking for.

```
.cell-right {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uLnqd35k/)

Vertical-align can be quite tricky at times and there's quite a lot of magic going on in there. Here's a nice detailed article breaking it down into understandable terms: [Vertical-align: All you need to know](http://christopheraue.net/2014/03/05/vertical-align/)